# compere 2 arrays (numbers)

Tags: arrays, c

am trying to compere 2 arrays formed from numbers
this is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    int a[n];
    int b[n];
    int ta=sizeof(a);

    printf("Enter la taille du tableux: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
// taking input a
    printf("Enter %d nombres: ",n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
// taking input b
    printf("Enter %d nombres: ",n);
    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[j]);
    }
//a to b
    for(k=0;k<ta;k++)
    {
        if(a[k] != b[k])
        {
            printf("Is ne sont pas identiques.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(k == n-1)
        {
            printf("Ils sont identiques.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

but am not getting the comparation after inserting the arrays, what am i doing wrong.

but am not getting the comparation after inserting the arrays, what am i doing wrong.

Comment: `int a[n]` is undefined because `n` is undefined at that point. No input has been provided yet, because `scanf` has not been called yet.

Comment: This also causes `sizeof(a)` be undefined.  But counting from `0` to `sizeof(a)` is not what you want anyway. You want to count from `0` to `n`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem. Please also specify the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: _Side note:_ For a slight speedup, you can remove your `else if` in the `for` loop. Just move the `printf("they are identical\n");` _after_ the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the array `a` and array b, you are taking incorrect array size.

```
int ta=sizeof(a);
```

Below code is give you expected output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
 {
    int n,i,j,k;
    int a[n];
    int b[n];
    //int ta=sizeof(a) calculate of array size is not correct

    printf("Enter la taille du tableux: ");  //Enter the array size
    scanf("%d", &n);

// taking input a
    printf("Enter %d integers: ",n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }



// taking input b
    printf("Enter %d nombre: ",n);
    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
    scanf("%d", &b[j]);
    }

//a to b
    for(k=0;k<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));k++)
    {
        if(a[i] != b[i])
        {
            printf("are not identical\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("they are identical\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Enter la taille du tableux: 3
Enter 3 integers: 1
2
3

Enter 3 nombre: 1
2
3

they are identical
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one small issue with your code, otherwise it is correct.
Change this:

```
int n,i,j,k;
int a[n]; // n is not initialized
int b[n];
int ta=sizeof(a);

printf("Enter la taille du tableux: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
```

To this:

```
int n,i,j,k;
int ta = sizeof(a);

printf("Enter la taille du tableux: ");
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* handle errors */ }
int a[n]; // now n is initialized
int b[n];
```

The problem is, that `n` is declared, but never assigned at first. That means, that `n` can be whatever value was at this memory before. This is called uninitialized memory. Here is a quick demonstration on that:

```
int main() {
    int arr[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        printf("%10d%c", arr[i], (i + 1) % 16 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
}
```